# AWS Lambda, adding firebase module and its dependencies to function for use with Angular Universal

Tags: firebase, aws-lambda, angularfire2, serverless-framework, aws-lambda-layers

I have an Angular Universal project deploying to AWS Lambda with SSR but I haven't managed to get firebase to work as a dependency with it. All the errors in the console are related to the firebase dependency & its dependencies.

**Method #1: Include firebase module**

```
package:
  exclude:
    - '!node_modules/firebase/**'
```

This adds firebase and now the errors moves to being unable to find dependencies of firebase and so on.

**Method #2: Just include all node modules**

This is an Angular project and I have 600mb+ of dependencies that build the app,

Method #3: Installing firebase inside my Angular 'dist' folder.

This will throw a runtime error:

```
Error: Failed to load gRPC binary module because it was not installed for the current system\nExpected directory: node-v64-linux-x64-glibc\nFound: [node-v64-win32-x64-unknown]\nThis problem can often be fixed by running \"npm rebuild\" on the current system\nOriginal error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v64-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node'",
```

**Method #4: serverless-webpack**

This will throw error during `sls deploy` saying it can't find webpack config, but it's right there in the root directory next to the serverlesss.yml and it's already used by angular universal, I can't overwrite it with different configs for serverless-webpack plugin.

**Method #5: Manual Lambda Layer**

I have tried making a layer with a package.json that has firebase as a dependency, ran npm install, made an archive of the `nodejs` folder that has the `node_modules` folder and uploaded it as a layer + manually added to my function.

Same error as #1, can't find the firebase module, this would also be overwritten by the serverless framework on my next deploy.

**Method #6: Lambda layer via serverless**

I've tried to piece these articles together to get something working  [Article 1](https://medium.com/appgambit/part-1-getting-started-with-aws-lambda-layers-1677a6b006), [Article 2](https://medium.com/appgambit/part-2-create-lambda-layers-with-serverless-framework-and-offline-support-ad2a5a8dabfb), [Article 3](https://serverless.com/blog/publish-aws-lambda-layers-serverless-framework/) and used the example from [this github](https://github.com/AppGambitStudio/serverless-lambda-layers) but switched moment with firebase.

But none of them worked, the serverless config:

```
layers:
  firebaseLayer:
    path: ../layers/firebase-layer
    compatibleRuntimes:
      - nodejs8.10
      - nodejs10.x
    package:
      include:
        - node_modules/**
```

Would throw: `No file matches include / exclude patterns`

I also have `const firebase = require('firebase');` inside my endpoint handler.

I've been trying to get this working for two whole days and it has been beyond frustrating. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Use `serverless-webpack` with the following configuration:

```
# serverless.yaml
service: serverless-webpack-firebase

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: "webpack.config.js"
    includeModules: true
    packager: "yarn"

functions:
  withWebpack:
    handler: handler.hello
```

```
// webpack.config.js

const path = require("path");
const slsw = require("serverless-webpack");
const nodeExternals = require("webpack-node-externals");

module.exports = {
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  target: "node",
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? "development" : "production",
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".json"]
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()]
};
```

`externals: [nodeExternals()]` will remove all external dependencies from the bundle and `includeModules: true` will still add them to the zip under `node_modules`

2. Use a Lambda layer:

```
# layer yaml
service: firebase-layer

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}

layers:
  firebase:
    path: ./layer
    description: Layer with all the required dependencies to use firebase
    compatibleRuntimes:
      - nodejs8.10
      - nodejs10.x
    licenseInfo: MIT
    retain: true
```

and

```
service: serverless-layer-firebase

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x
  stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
  region: ${opt:region, 'us-east-1'}

plugins:
  - serverless-webpack
  - serverless-pseudo-parameters

package:
  individually: true

custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: "webpack.config.js"
    includeModules: false
    packager: "yarn"

functions:
  withLayer:
    handler: handler.hello

    layers:
      - arn:aws:lambda:${self:provider.region}:#{AWS::AccountId}:layer:firebase:1
```

Same `webpack.config.js`, but this time with `includeModules: false` as we don't need the dependencies in the zip file (they are loaded with the layer).

Layer structure:

[image]

Repository is available here: https://github.com/erezrokah/serverless-webpack-firebase

See the differences in package size:

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'll give it a go sometime this weekend, I ended up making a layer manually as I couldn't figure out the serverless way of doing it, will give yours a try as I'd preffer it the way you've described it

Comment: Ended up using a layer, then giving up on serverless and aws lambda altogether after a couple of painful months.